# How to set an image as background for different mobile screen resolutions?

Tags: html, css, image

How can I set an image as background to work with multiple mobile different screen resolutions? For example if I am using it on iPhone4 which has a smaller resolution than iPhone6 without stretch it or crop it and show half of the image. I wish to know if there is any chance to show de middle of the image instead of coping it and show half of the image and half white.

```
.landing-page{
    background: url(../img/landing-portrait.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

If I use this then will show like almost half of the image and then everything is white in bottom. If I use height: 100%; then the white space in the bottom is getting lower and the image is getting larger in right side and the content is not in middle anymore.

Comment: add media rules in css for mobile devices and put this background-size: 100%; for them

Comment: use `background-position:center center` to show the center part of the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `background-size: 100%;` to achieve what you are looking for.

> background-size: 100%; stretches the background image independently in
>   both directions to completely cover the content area - [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size)

**For instance,**

```
.landing-page{
    background: url(../img/landing-portrait.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You can refer more for the same [**HERE**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> This answer does not answer your question directly. But it gives you
>   an alternative and can direct you to a new approach.

---

I suggest you could use the [`figure`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp) and the [`source`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_source.asp) tags. Please read upon those tags. I believe they might be used more often in the future in regard to responsive design.

For portable media devices often you don't need high resolution, and you can speed up the load process by loading/displaying images with smaller memory footprint.

Example:

```
<figure>
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 750px)" srcset="images/still_life-800_large_1x.jpg 1x, images/still_life-1600_large_2x.jpg 2x" type="image/jpeg">
    <source media="(min-width: 500px)" srcset="images/still_life-1000_medium.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
    <img src="images/still_life-500_small.jpg" alt="Still Life">
    <figcaption>Still Life</figcaption>
  </picture>
</figure>
```

> This example is a bit advanced (use of `srcset`), but support for the
>   srcset is expected to come in the future (I learned that from the
>   instructor of Responsive Design course on Udacity). You would probably
>   simply use the `src` attribute.

Basically what you specify here is a media query (the size of the viewport) and the corresponding source(s). The `srcset` can choose dynamically the image to load depending on the device pixel ratio of the screen (for iPad2 for example you can display more crispy images then).

You can use the usual `img` tag to fail gracefully in case a browser does not support the `source` tag.

Comment: @alexanderfarkas I am not too acquainted with polyfill. Please feel free to edit my answer, I'd be happy to approve.